# Python kubernetes client Get pod Ready state time

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am writing python script for kubernetes using python client.

I want to count or calculate the POD `Ready` state time.

In 30 Second pod Ready or similar.

Right now i am planning to use

```
'status': {
    'conditions': [
      {
        'last_probe_time': None,
        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019,
        12,
        17,
        13,
        14,
        58,
        tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'message': None,
        'reason': None,
        'status': 'True',
        'type': 'Initialized'
      },
      {
        'last_probe_time': None,
        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019,
        12,
        17,
        13,
        16,
        2,
        tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'message': None,
        'reason': None,
        'status': 'True',
        'type': 'Ready'
      },
      {
        'last_probe_time': None,
        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019,
        12,
        17,
        13,
        16,
        2,
        tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'message': None,
        'reason': None,
        'status': 'True',
        'type': 'ContainersReady'
      },
      {
        'last_probe_time': None,
        'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019,
        12,
        17,
        13,
        14,
        58,
        tzinfo=tzutc()),
        'message': None,
        'reason': None,
        'status': 'True',
        'type': 'PodScheduled'
      }
    ]
```

But looking forward to directly can get total Ready state time from Pod initialised time.

can anybody suggest better way.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't something specific, you already have the data you need. Just go through the list and find the two last_transition_times for Ready and Initialized and then subtract.

Comment: thanks a lot for writing answer, really helpful. same as i thought.

Comment: No they aren't, you can see in what you posted that they are 1 minute 4 seconds apart.

Comment: Yes i got it. Thankyou.